# $1 and $2 variable shell script recursive is function is received as same

Tags: bash, shell

I have written a recursive function to iterate through directories, iteration should exit when the specified depth is reached. Both the entry directory and maximum depth value are passed as parameters to the function.

```
perform_fragmented_copy() { 
    echo -e "perform_fragmented_copy: $1 at depth $2"
    while [ "$1" ] && [ "$2" -le $n_max_depth ]; 
    do
        declare -i n_entry_size=$(du -sb $1  | awk '{print $1}')
        if [ $sz_remainig_destination -gt $n_entry_size ]
        then
            echo -e "perform_fragmented_copy: can do the copy";
        else
            echo -e "perform_fragmented_copy: cannot, iterating again";
            declare -i n_curr_depth=$(($2+1))
            perform_fragmented_copy "$1"/* $n_curr_depth
        fi
        shift
    done 
    echo -e "perform_fragmented_copy: exiting: $1 at depth $2"
}
```

Invoked as

```
sz_remainig_destination=10000
n_max_depth=5 
perform_fragmented_copy $1 0
```

Output is:

```
perform_fragmented_copy: /home/ROSS-82/ at depth 0
perform_fragmented_copy: cannot, iterating again
perform_fragmented_copy: /home/ROSS-82//82 at depth /home/ROSS-82//ross_reader-82
./ftest.sh: line 69: [: /home/ROSS-82//ross_reader-82: integer expression expected
perform_fragmented_copy: exiting: /home/ROSS-82//82 at depth /home/ROSS-82//ross_reader-82
./ftest.sh: line 69: [: : integer expression expected
perform_fragmented_copy: exiting: 0 at depth
```

In output at fist recursion `$2` is received as integer which is 0

```
perform_fragmented_copy: /home/ROSS-82/ at depth 0
```

In output at second recursion `$2` is received as `$1`

```
perform_fragmented_copy: /home/ROSS-82//82 at depth /home/ROSS-82//ross_reader-82
```

I have tried many ways to resolve this, and googled for solutions, but no results yet.

Comment: The wildcard `"$1"/*` expands to more than one argument when the directory `$1` contains more than one file. The simplest fix is probably to reverse the order of the arguments, though you'll probably need to do something useful with the additional arguments, too; what exactly is unclear because you don't explain what this code should do. Tangentially, see also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Maybe you want to recurse separately for each file: `for f in "$1"/*; do perform_fragmented_copy "$f" $n_curr_depth; done`

Comment: it's a bit hard to know for sure what the issue may be since the provided code is not generating the sample output (eg, output does match function's `echo` calls); having said that ... 1st guess would be that `"$1"/*` is expanding to more than one space delimited value (thus pushing `$n_curr_depth` out to position $3, $4 or later); I'd suggest enabling debug mode (`set -xv` at the top level) and/or add some additional `echo` calls to the function (eg, first line of function == `echo $@`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the depth to the first argument. Then you can shift this out of the argument list before the loop, and the loop processes the remaining arguments with `$1` and `shift`.

```
perform_fragmented_copy() { 
    depth=$1
    shift
    echo -e "perform_fragmented_copy: $@ at depth $depth"

    if [ "$depth" -ge "$n_max_depth" ]
    then return
    fi
    declare -i n_curr_depth=$(($depth+1))

    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; 
    do
        declare -i n_entry_size=$(du -sb "$1" | awk '{print $1}')
        if [ $sz_remainig_destination -gt $n_entry_size ]
        then
            echo -e "perform_fragmented_copy: can do the copy";
        else
            echo -e "perform_fragmented_copy: cannot, iterating again";
            perform_fragmented_copy $n_curr_depth "$1"/* 
        fi
        shift
    done 
    echo -e "perform_fragmented_copy: exiting: at depth $depth"
}
```

You can't refer to `$1` in the `exiting` message at the end, because the loop ends when all the parameters have been shifted away. The loop ends when `$1` is empty.

Comment: Maybe also fix the spelling of _"remaining"_ in the variable names.